# Is the CRM 4 / CRM 2011 API a "true" web service

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I was in a meeting and I was told that the CRM API is not a true web service.  I always just assumed that the API was a web service since you have to download the WSDL to use it.  So, is it a web service or not?

I just wanted to clarify, I'm talking about the API that you compile into a .net executable, not the javascript "fetchXML" or "oData" calls.

Comment: Microsoft use the term "web service" in their [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309557.aspx), and I'm inclined to think they know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ask what they define a "true" web service to be.  Based on the [W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-ws-gloss-20040211/#webservice) it meets the following criteria:

- support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network
- interface described in a machine-processable format (specifically WSDL)
- Other systems interact with the Web service in a manner prescribed by its description using SOAP-messages, typically conveyed using HTTP with an XML serialization in conjunction with other Web-related standards

That said - it *does* have some characteristics that make it different than traditional web services (such as the WSDL dynamically supporting entity/property changes), but form an architecture standpoint it is a web service in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You access it by adding a web service reference and you can call it using SOAP requests from JavaScript so I'd say yes.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify, I'm talking about the API that you compile into a .net executable, not the javascript "fetchXML" or "oData" calls.

Comment: Me too. You can call the web service elements from JavaScript too, which is sometimes necessary.